# SaaS Architecture Question from Newbie

Tags: saas

I have developed a number of departmental client-server applications, and am now ready to begin working on moving one of these applications to a SaaS model. I have done some basic web development, but I'm a newbie when it comes to SaaS architectures.

One of the first questions that comes to mind as I try to design the architecture is the question of single vs. multi tenancy. The pros and cons of each vary significantly depending on the type of application and scale required, so I'd like to describe my application and scale needs below, and hope others can comment on how I should get started with the architecture.

The client-server application currently consists of a Firebird database and a Windows application. The database contains about 20 tables containing a few thousand records in 4 primary tables, and a few hundred records in various lookup and related tables. Although the number of records is small, the size can get large, as the database can contain large BLOBS. Each customer sets up their own database and has a handful of users within the organization connected to it. When I update the db schema, a new windows application is released, and it checks the db schema and then applies the updates as needed.

For the SaaS application, I am designing for 100's (not 1000's or millions) of new customers per year. My first thought was to go with a multi tenancy model to make updates easy (shut down apply the updates to one database, and then start up). On the other hand, a single tenancy model would provide a means to roll updates out to a group of customers at a time, and spread the risk of data corruption - i.e. if something goes wrong with a database, it will impact one customer instead of all customers. With this idea, I was thinking of having a single web front-end which would connect to a single customer database upon login. Thus, when a new customer creates an account, a new database would be created (each customer would have their own db with multiple users as needed for the customer).

In this model, a db update would require either a process to go through each db to apply schema changes, or a trigger upon logging in to initiate a schema update similar to the client-server model currently in use.

Can anyone point me to information for similar applications which have been ported from client-server to SaaS? Or provide any pointers to consider? Basically I'm looking for architecture examples of taking a departmental application and making it available as a self service website for multiple customers. Thanks for any suggestions, resources, etc.

Answer (score 7):

If you have multiple databases which you roll out in a staged manner to reduce the likelihood of breaking all of your customers, you will have to address the issue of what to do if the DB structure changes.  You will either have to be rigorous maintaining backward compatibility, or else deploy separate versions of your code base and manage which tenants are associated with which databases.

We are providing our application using a SaaS model as well.

It was initially a Windows app which worked similarly to your multiple-database proposal.  Upon login, the app would authenticate against a single licensee database which would respond with connection information for a database specific to that licensee.  The nice thing about this was that it provided 1) physical separation of licensee data, which our customers liked and 2) enabled us to physically locate the database on a server geographically closer to the users, which both improves performance and avoids some potentially tricky legal and regulatory issues with providing data across country boundaries.

Since the app was a thick client app, we could get away with making database changes and pushing them out to one licensee at a time.  When we were ready to upgrade, we could push out an updated thick client in conjunction with the new database--thereby ensuring that the codebase was a match with the database.  As long as the common licensee authentication database stayed consistent, this worked fairly well.

On the other hand, this solution brought with it all of the problems of maintaining and managing a thick client approach which finally lead us down the thin client, browser-based approach.

In our new model, everything is in a single database.  When we have updates, we push the code and the DB out at the same time.  This solves the problem of keeping the code base consistent with the database structure.  However, we are now confronted with the issues mentioned above, which we have yet to resolve.